# How to implement timeout in asyncio server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, session-timeout

Below is a simple echo server. But if the client does not send anything for 10 seconds, I want to close the connection.

```
import asyncio


async def process(reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    print("awaiting for data")
    line = await reader.readline()
    print(f"received {line}")
    writer.write(line)
    print(f"sent {line}")
    await writer.drain()
    print(f"Drained")


async def timeout(task: asyncio.Task, duration):
    print("timeout started")
    await asyncio.sleep(duration)
    print("client unresponsive, cancelling")
    task.cancel()
    print("task cancelled")


async def new_session(reader, writer):
    print("new session started")
    task = asyncio.create_task(process(reader, writer))
    timer = asyncio.create_task(timeout(task, 10))
    await task
    print("task complete")
    timer.cancel()
    print("timer cancelled")
    writer.close()
    print("writer closed")


async def a_main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(new_session, port=8088)
    await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(a_main())
```

If the client sends a message, it works fine. But the other case, when client is silent, it does not work

When client sends message:

```
new session started
awaiting for data
timeout started
received b'slkdfjsdlkfj\r\n'
sent b'slkdfjsdlkfj\r\n'
Drained
task complete
timer cancelled
writer closed
```

When client is silent after opening connection

```
new session started
awaiting for data
timeout started
client unresponsive, cancelling
task cancelled
```

There is no `task complete`, `timer cancelled`, `writer closed`.

1. <del>What is the issue with above code?</del>
2. Is there a better way to implement timeouts?

---

**Update**

Figured out the problem, Looks like the task was actually cancelled, but the exception got silently ignored, Fixed the problem by catching `CancelledError`

```
async def new_session(reader, writer):
    print("new session started")
    task = asyncio.create_task(process(reader, writer))
    timer = asyncio.create_task(timeout(task, 10))
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"Task took too long and was cancelled by timer")
    print("task complete")
    timer.cancel()
    print("timer cancelled")
    writer.close()
    print("writer closed")
```

Second part still remains. Is there a better way to implement timeouts?

---

**Update2**

Complete code using `wait_for`. The timeout code is no longer needed. Check accepted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960499) below:

```
async def new_session(reader, writer):
    print("new session started")
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(process(reader, writer), timeout=5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as te:
        print(f'time is up!{te}')
    finally:
        writer.close()
        print("writer closed")
```

Comment: You can use `asyncio.wait_for` instead of `timeout`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks. Do you want to add it as an answer? I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to implement timeouts?

You can use [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) instead of `timeout`. It has similar semantics, but already comes with asyncio. Also, you can await the future it returns to detect if the timeout has occurred.

Answer (score 10):

I use the following code when making a connection. I'd suggest using wait_for similarly for your code.

```
fut = asyncio.open_connection( self.host, self.port, loop=self.loop )
try:
   r, w = await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout=self.connection_timeout)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
   pass
```

Comment: `open_connection` is when you are a client. The question is for server.

Comment: It is an example of how to use wait_for which is the pythonic solution for what you want to do.

Comment: I didn't realise it can be used for any awaitable. Upvoted.