# How to implement timeout in asyncio trasport/protocol server?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

This is a lower level variation of a similar previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53950344/1499402).

The [TCP Echo Server example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server) in the [Transports and Protocols docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#transports-and-protocols) will never timeout an established socket connection.
In order to add a 5 seconds timeout, I simply scheduled a callback with a `loop.call_later` call.

```
import asyncio


class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        # ---> here the timeout is implemented <---
        self.timer = asyncio.get_running_loop().call_later(5, transport.close)
        print("connection made")

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.transport.write(data)
        self.transport.close()
        print("echo sent")

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        self.timer.cancel()
        print("connection lost")


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    server = await loop.create_server(lambda: EchoServerProtocol(), "127.0.0.1", 8888)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

I was wondering if this is can be considered a "canonical" solution, or better methods can be devised.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to explicitly manage the connection as returned by `loop.create_connection()` together with the new `asyncio.timeout()` API introduced in Python3.11.

Comment: Bar monkey patching the python libs, I do not see a method for doing this: I have access only to the object returned by `loop.create_server`. Your suggestion could work for a client program, where you call `loop.create_connection` explicitly. Moreover I would like to have the possibility to _reset_ the timeout when activity on the socket happens, and only timeout idling connections.